# IntelliJ IDEA(2017.1.2 EAP) : Asking user name and password for subversion every time

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Is there any way to force the IDE to remember the username and password, so I do not have to reenter them again after restart?

Ticking the box(Save credentials) on the pop-up windows did not help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141048

Please check if [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141048#comment=27-1795556) helps

Answer (score 0):

MacOS: 10.12.4 
svn: 1.9.4

Preferences -> Subversion(under Version Control) -> Tick "Enable interactive mode"(under General tab)